# Request size vs Server load

Tags: performance, http, parsing, httprequest, conventions

I was writing the spec on how to organize the query parameters that are sent in a HTTP Request, and I came up with the following:

All parameters a prefixed with the entity to which they belong, an example "a.b", which is read "b of entity a", that way each parameter would be clearly mapped to the corresponding entity, but what if there were two different entities that share a query paramater?, to  avoid repetition and request size I came up with the following micro format. To have a request wide entity called `shared` each property of `shared` will represent a property that is shared among entities, e.g.

```
POST /app/my/resource   HTTP/1.1
a.p = v
b.p = v
c.p = v
d.p = v
```

Here it is clear that property `p` is shared among `a,b,c` and `d` so this could be sent as

```
POST /app/my/resource HTTP/1.1
shared.p = a:b:c:d%v
```

Now, the request is smaller and I'm being a bit more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), however this adds an extra burden to the server as it has to parse the string to process the values.

Probably in my example the differences are insignificant and I could chose either, but I'd like to know what do you think about it, what would you prefer, maybe the size of the request does not matter, or maybe the parsing of the string is not such a big deal when the length is short, but what happens when we scale the size of both the request and string which one would be better, what are the tradeoffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing is a compression algorithm. Beware that payloads often are compressed on protocol layer already (HTTP, gzip Content-Type, see [HTTP compression examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)). Compression algorithms are advanced enough to compress duplicate string-items, so probably you won't win much by a custom compression.

Generally try not to optimize prematurely. First show that you are having a response-time or payload-size issue and then optimize. Your compression algorithm itself is a good idea, but it makes payload more complicated as normal key/value pairs (xxx-form-urlencoded Content-Type). For maintenance reasons head for the simplest design possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw this out there, I think the answer would depend on what platform your back-end servers are running to process the requests. For example, the last time that I checked, the Perl-based mod_perl can parse those strings much faster something like ASP.NET.